# Using Entity Framework to return a table of data to iterate against

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I am currently using EF 6 to do the following. Execute a stored procedure, then bring in the data I need to use. The data is usually 30-40 rows per application run.

I then iterate over the var, object, table (whatever you would like to call it), performing similar (sometimes different) tasks on each row. It works great. I am able to create an Entity object, expose the different complex functions of it, and then create a var to iterate over.

Like:

```
foreach (var result in StoredProcedureResult)
{
string strFirstname = result.FirstName
string strLastName = result.LastName
//more logic goes here using those variables and interacting with another app

}
```

I recently thought it would be cool if I had a class solely for accessing the data. In this way, I could just reference that class, toss the corresponding connection string into my app.config, and then I can keep the two sets of logic separate. So when attempting to do the above in that structure, I get to the point at which, you can't return a var, or when I attempt to match object return type. The return type of the execution of a stored procedure is object (which I can't iterate on).

So my question is, how does one get to the above example, except, the var result, get returned from this data access class?

If I am missing something, or its not possible because I am doing this incorrectly, do let me know. It appeared right in my head.

Comment: have you looked at function imports in EF?

Comment: @Marty hey thanks for responding. I was under the impression I was already using function imports? Is that not what the above code snippet is a result of? The StoredProcedureResult was from doing the following: `EntityName db = new EntityName();
            var StoredProcedureResult = db.Sp_That_Returns_SomeRows_And_Columns();
            db.Dispose(); `

Comment: first: if `EntityName` is the class name of your DbContext then the more usual way would be with `using` instead of the `Dispose` [see doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime). second: function imports should allow you to specify that the procedure returns a complex type, that way you'll get that type returned instead of object

Comment: @Marty okay gotcha, will wrap that in a using.hmm, it does look like it is set in the drop down to "complex". So the fully qualified type VS is calling it is: `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`

Comment: @Marty so okay, the above seemed to fix the return type issue, and `ObjectResult` is a return type you can iterate over. One more small issue. So in my post with the example of returning the first or last name, you can see that the get and set for the specific columns are created, and in the DataAccessLayer I can see those methods. The issue is, in the project referencing the DAL, `string strFirstname = result.FirstName` there is no intellisense showing the column list as you type `result.`, so I think I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Marty got a bit further, you can do `ObjectResult<NameOfYourFunction_Result)` this is the proper return type, and this works. My issue is, I used a bit of an idea another person's answer on Stack gave me. Application -- Data Access Layer -- Shared Layer, each of these being a separate project, and I was under the impression I could contain all my Data access stuff in one place, and then share it with the Shared Layer, then make a reference from the main app to the shared project, and that would expose access to the Shared Project methods calling the data access layer

Comment: issue is, everything checks out except the main application project wants me to make a reference to the data access layer. However, my goal was to not have to make a reference to this project, and instead make a reference to the Shared Layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to describe the architecture in full. But based on your comments you can do the following (this is not the definitive nor the only way how to do it):

1. in your data access project you keep the DBContext class, all the code for the stored procedure call and also the class that defines the result of the SP call, let's call it class A;
2. in your shared layer project - I would suggest calling it Service layer - you can create a XYService class, that has a method e.g. `GetListOfX` that connects to the DB and calls the procedure, if needed this method can also perform some logic, but more importantly: it doesn't return class A, but returns a new class B (this one is defined in the service layer, or can be defined in yet another project - that might be the true shared/common project; as it would be just a definition of common structures it isn't really a layer);
3. in your application layer you work only with the method `GetListOfX` of the XYService and the class B, that way you don't need a reference to the data access project

In a trivial case the class B has the same properties as the class A. But depending on your needs the class B can have additional properties/functionality it can also ignore some properties of A or even combine multiple properties into one: e.g. combining the `FirstName` and `LastName` as one property called simply `Name`.

Basically what you are looking for is the multi-tier application architecture (usually 3-4 tier). The full extent of such approach (which includes heavy usage of concepts like interfaces and dependency injection) might not be suitable or needed based on your goals, e.g. if you are building just a small application for yourself with a couple of functions or you know there won't be any reuse of the components of the final solution, then this approach is too wasteful and you can work faster with everything in one project - you should still apply principles like [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Implemented this solution. With your reading links, and great explanation, I think I have now begun making a decent tiered application. It was not so much of the should i do it, more of the can I. With this help, I was able to. Thanks Marty!

Comment: I think the only place I may have deviated from your direction was in the first step. My Data layer looks more like a service class with just methods that use EF to call the SP then return the result. Which I think was a little different than when you said: **all the code for the stored procedure call and also the class that defines the result of the SP call**

Comment: @MikeCMR there are multiple ways of how to use EF, in the simple cases you don't even need SPs and can query the tables using LINQ, if you haven't yet looked at it I would suggest you read about it ;)